# How do I do geocoding and routing with OpenStreetMap?

Tags: api, routes, geocode, openstreetmap

Because Google Maps API is not available in Israel (see [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=664)) I want to use OpenStreetMap.  I'm confused by all the different ways to do geocoding, i.e. finding lat,long for an address.

I'm also looking for the best way to do routing, i.e. display a route between two locations, using OSM.

I'm looking for JavaScript on the client and .NET on my server.

I'm also looking for a solution that will work with names in Hebrew, but I do not think this is a limitation.

Comment: This question is from 3 years ago, and now Google Maps API supports geocoding, however with very rigid API use limits, so using it is still a problem. Is there any new solution for this you may have encountered? Thanks!

Comment: Dor, I have attempted to use the Waze API, but it was quite cumbersome.

Comment: Waze API is not an option for these days, as it may be closed if they are bought by Facebook, like they did with face.com. So I understand Nominatim is still the best option even today?

Comment: This questions might be a better fit for gis.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 30):

### Routing

[MapQuest open](http://open.mapquestapi.com/) offers an [Open Directions Service](http://open.mapquestapi.com/directions/) and an [Open Guidance Service](http://open.mapquestapi.com/guidance/).

Additional information about Routing in OpenStreetMap can be found in the [Routing article on the OSM wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing).

### Geocoding

Cloudmade's *Web Maps API* includes a geocoder. The geocoders currently used on [OpenStreetMap's main site](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) are [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) and [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/). There is now also an [open geocoding service by MapQuest](http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/).

Comment: I've started to use Nominatim as the geocoder - looking good

Comment: I'm happy with Cloudmades' routing service. Simple api, query response times are okay, all routes have been correct so far.

Comment: It bears mentioning that as of this comment, Cloudmade no longer provides routing for non-enterprise users.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Thanks. I have removed the CloudMade bit.

Comment: Is there any free library/service/api for the given problem?
Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it is permissible to use the MapQuest geocoding results on a non-MapQuest map, at least that's how I read their terms which does not distinguish between the various geocoding APIs they offer.

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://openrouteservice.org/. They did routing using OSM already.

Comment: I don't see how this helps as they do not offer an API, unless I'm missing it.

Comment: ORS could maybe be used as an Routing API. Use http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/index.php/OpenRouteService#ORS_.22API.22 and download the route description as an XML.

Comment: ORS seems not cover Israel.  See http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Image:ORS_Coverage.png