# OpenStreetMap Geocoder other than Nominatim

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, geocoding, openstreetmap

Are there any other geocoders that are built to use OpenStreetMap data other than Nominatim? I've looked at Nominatim but am unfamiliar with PHP and would like to find or build a geocoder in .Net/ASP that uses OSM data. Would like to find an open source one as a starting point but if there aren't any others is there someone that can explain how it works so I can implement my own. I would like it in .Net instead of using the PHP version so I can customize and extend it which I'm unable to do in PHP. After I get it working in .Net I would like to open source it as I have not found a good geocoder that runs on OSM data that was made for .Net

Comment: Are you stuck on OpenStreetMap data?  If you can use a different API, you might have more options.

Comment: @Jeffrey I'm not "stuck" with OSM data. I don't want to use and API so much as build a geocoder in c# that will use OSM and or other data. I was just looking at Nominatim as a starting point but it's mostly in PHP. I would like to open source it after it works since there are none in c# that I see.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question here: [How do I do geocoding and routing with OpenStreetMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063093/how-do-i-do-geocoding-and-routing-with-openstreetmap). The answer there mentions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Source_Routing_Machine

But to answer your question directly: the OpenStreetMap Wiki has a page [dedicated to geocoders](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Geocoding). After Nominatim, http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/MapQuest seems (on a brief look) to be the next best bet.