# Geocoding and route planning API options

Tags: geocoding

I want to develop a system for finding possible routes for delivery drivers for a food delivery service and wanted to know what API options are out there. I am trying to find an API I can call from the backend that can do geocoding and find routes and times between points so I can calculate possible delivery address grouping for drivers. Most APIs I have seen have usage limits or say they need to be used with maps while I want to be able to make calls from a backend server without a map. I have seen googles and mapquests APIs but are there others maybe I am not aware that allow for a large number of calls?

Comment: try looking into some of the responses to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063093/how-do-i-do-geocoding-and-routing-with-openstreetmap

Comment: Thanks. I had seen that earlier but seemed that most of those were not for enterprise use so was curious if there were additional ones designed for large scale use.

Comment: There's alway the ESRI suite of products. These definitely *are* designed for Enterprise use, however they are more than a bit spendy.